# Problems with add_action

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a plugin in wordpress and want to include a JS script in the  tags area only when i'm viewing the menu page.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page');

function register_custom_menu_page() {
  add_menu_page('Home', 'PCPAL', 'manage_options',  'pcpalmain', 'da_controller',   '', 99);
}

function DA_controller()
{
   add_action('admin_head', 'da_admin_head');
}

function da_admin_head()
{
  echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".plugins_url('js/pcpal.js', __FILE__)."'></script>";
}
```

This script work if i move the add_action('admin_head', 'da_admin_head'); outside the DA_function function.

Comment: The add_Action doesn't work when placed in the da_functionn

Comment: I see 2 da_ functions. Which one? I assume DA_controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you are including JS the wrong way you need to `enqueue` it -> `http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script`
2. your first add_action goes to the `admin_head` you need to use `admin_init`

tutorial about enqueue-ing 
http://halfelf.org/2012/jquery-why-u-no-enqueued/

Comment: Great stuff.  that has worked using wp_enqueue_script('pcpaljs', plugins_url('js/pcpal.js', __FILE__));

Answer (score 0):

Your Code has a lot  off issues.... Let me help you to correct it....
Here is your code

```
1. add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page');

2. function register_custom_menu_page() {
3.  add_menu_page('Home', 'PCPAL', 'manage_options',  'pcpalmain', 'da_controller',   '', 4. 99);
5. }

6. function DA_controller()
7. {
8.    add_action('admin_head', 'da_admin_head');
9. }

10. function da_admin_head()
{
11.  echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".plugins_url('js/pcpal.js', __FILE__)."'></script>";
}
```

I have added some numbering so that I can point you where is the problems....

On line 1, you added a function to admin_menu hook. ON line 3, you added a function named da_controller for creating a admin menue.

But one number 6 you just misspelled it.

Well, I do not have enough time for today... But this edited codes must work for now....

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page');

function register_custom_menu_page() {
  add_menu_page('Home', 'PCPAL', 'manage_options',  'pcpalmain', 'da_controller',   '', 99);
}

function da_controller()
{   
   wp_enqueue_script( 'pcpal', 'js_url', array(), '1.0.0', false );

}
```